# Clearing console causes Eclipse to shut down

Tags: eclipse, fatal-error

Everytime I try clearing the console in eclipse via the clear console button it causes Eclipse to unexpectedly die.

```
    Process:               eclipse [87175]
    Path:                  /Applications/eclipse-neon/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
    Identifier:            org.eclipse.platform.ide
    Version:               4.6.3 (4.6.3.M20170301-0400)
    Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
    Parent Process:        ??? [1]
    Responsible:           eclipse [87175]

    Date/Time:             2018-03-22 10:39:44.048 -0400
    OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.3 (17D102)
    Report Version:        12
    Bridge OS Version:     3.0 (14Y661)
    Time Awake Since Boot: 84000 seconds
    Time Since Wake:       3500 seconds
    Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

    Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
    Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000001b9d0a778
    Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

    VM Regions Near 0x1b9d0a778:
        MALLOC_SMALL           0000000149000000-000000014a800000 [ 24.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
    --> 
        VM_ALLOCATE            00000006c0000000-0000000710000000 [  1.2G] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

    Application Specific Information:
    abort() called

    Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff68878e3e __pthread_kill + 10
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff689b7150 pthread_kill + 333
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff687d5312 abort + 127
    3   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000106c89d63 os::abort(bool) + 25
    4   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000106db0e3a VMError::report_and_die() + 2304
    5   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000106c8b98e JVM_handle_bsd_signal + 1131
    6   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000106c87bf3 signalHandler(int, __siginfo*, void*) + 47
    7   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff689aaf5a _sigtramp + 26
    8   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff4bf4104d CA::Layer::prepare_commit(CA::Transaction*) + 555
    9   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff41258831 CGBlt_copyBytes + 357
    10  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff41259e73 argb32_image + 4999
    11  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff415c2051 ripl_Mark + 22
    12  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff415be469 RIPLayerBltImage + 1035
    13  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff41329f2b ripc_RenderImage + 228
    14  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff4132b546 ripc_DrawImage + 847
    15  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff41294ad0 CGContextDelegateDrawImage + 41
    16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3e58934f __backing_store_DrawImage_block_invoke + 70
    17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3e585681 backing_store_delegate + 962
    18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3e87fa56 backing_store_DrawImage.llvm.933B347B + 514
    19  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff41294ad0 CGContextDelegateDrawImage + 41
    20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3e8808f0 backing_store_DrawWindowContents.llvm.933B347B + 1197
    21  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff4129e1cc CGContextDelegateDrawWindowContents + 59
    22  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fff628afaf8 SLContextCopyWindowContentsToRect + 178
    23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3e760ccb _NSRenderImageFromWindow + 1454
    24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3e7606fd _NXScroll + 451
    25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3ed0e3a6 NSCopyBitsFromGraphicsContext + 312
    26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3ed0e268 NSCopyBits + 58
    27  libswt-pi-cocoa-4629.jnilib     0x000000012b534db0 Java_org_eclipse_swt_internal_cocoa_OS_NSCopyBits + 288
    28  ???                             0x0000000108d80a74 0 + 4443343476
    29  ???                             0x0000000108d712bd 0 + 4443280061
    30  ???                             0x0000000108d712bd 0 + 4443280061
    31  ???                             0x000000010a981a24 0 + 4472707620
    32  ???                             0x0000000108d712bd 0 + 4443280061
    33  ???                             0x0000000108d712bd 0 + 4443280061
    34  ???                             0x0000000108d71302 0 + 4443280130
    35  ???                             0x000000010d64abc4 0 + 4519668676


    Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
      rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fffa177f340  rcx: 0x00007ffeefbfb4c8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
      rdi: 0x0000000000000307  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007ffeefbfb500  rsp: 0x00007ffeefbfb4c8
       r8: 0x00007fffa175ef78   r9: 0x0000000000000040  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
      r12: 0x0000000000000307  r13: 0x00000000000000d4  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x000000000000002d
      rip: 0x00007fff68878e3e  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fffa175d148

    Logical CPU:     0
    Error Code:      0x02000148
    Trap Number:     133

    External Modification Summary:
      Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
        task_for_pid: 246
        thread_create: 0
        thread_set_state: 0
      Calls made by this process:
        task_for_pid: 0
        thread_create: 0
        thread_set_state: 0
      Calls made by all processes on this machine:
        task_for_pid: 4655979
        thread_create: 0
        thread_set_state: 0

    VM Region Summary:
    ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=462.9M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=462.9M(100%)
    Writable regions: Total=5.2G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=5.2G(100%)

                                    VIRTUAL   REGION 
    REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
    ===========                     =======  ======= 
    Accelerate framework               256K        3 
    Activity Tracing                   256K        2 
    CG backing stores                 20.4M       11 
    CG image                          2572K      173 
    CoreAnimation                        4K        2 
    CoreGraphics                         8K        2 
    CoreImage                           40K        7 
    CoreUI image data                 1712K       20 
    CoreUI image file                  188K        5 
    Foundation                          28K        3 
    IOKit                             7940K        2 
    Image IO                           260K        3 
    Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        2 
    MALLOC                           659.9M      114 
    MALLOC guard page                   64K       17 
    MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)           2048K        3         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
    Memory Tag 242                      12K        2 
    Memory Tag 251                      24K        2 
    OpenGL GLSL                        256K        4 
    STACK GUARD                        588K       72 
    Stack                             72.3M       72 
    Stack Guard                       56.1M       39 
    VM_ALLOCATE                        5.4G       73 
    VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)           160.0M        4         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
    __DATA                            38.1M      353 
    __FONT_DATA                          4K        2 
    __GLSLBUILTINS                    2588K        2 
    __LINKEDIT                       198.8M       19 
    __TEXT                           264.1M      351 
    __UNICODE                          560K        2 
    mapped file                       91.2M      290 
    shared memory                      812K       14 
    ===========                     =======  ======= 
    TOTAL                              7.0G     1638 
    TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     6.8G     1638 

    Model: MacBookPro13,3, BootROM MBP133.0238.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.9 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.38f7
    Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 530, Intel HD Graphics 530, Built-In
    Graphics: Radeon Pro 460, AMD Radeon Pro 460, PCIe, 4 GB
    Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C31473332443450472D30393320
    Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C31473332443450472D30393320
    AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x15A), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.5.1a3)
    Bluetooth: Version 6.0.2f2, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
    Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
    USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
    USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
    USB Device: Keyboard Hub
    USB Device: Fitbit Base Station
    USB Device: Apple Keyboard
    USB Device: USB-C VGA Multiport Adapter
    USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
    USB Device: iBridge
    USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
    USB Device: Elements 25A2
    USB Device: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
    USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
    Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse crashing after clearing the console under macOS Sierra and macOS High Sierra is a known issue. See [Bug 526183 - Clear console on "Run as Eclipse Application" instance crashes IDE](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526183):

> 1) Launch an Eclipse Plugin project by right click -> Run as ->
>   Eclipse Application
>
> 2) A new Eclipse instance appears
>
> 3) Click the clear console icon in the Console tab
>
> 4) Eclipse crashes, stacktrace (at the first Eclipse instance console)

That bug is a duplicate of [Bug 502711 - [Cocoa][10.12] crashes on „macOS Sierra“ related to NSCopyBits](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=502711) which has been fixed in Oxygen, but not in Neon since "[there are no more releases for Neon. Maintenance builds are available only for Oxygen](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=502711#c22)".

Since you are running Neon you need to upgrade Eclipse to Oxygen to resolve the issue.

---

Updated on 8/16/18 to clarify that simply upgrading from Neon to Oxygen, or installing Oxygen is not necessarily sufficient. You need to be running Oxygen M7 or newer to benefit from the fix for [Bug 502711](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=502711) mentioned above.

Comment: This also occurs on Oxygen. I have the following installed. Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Oxygen Release Milestone 2 (4.7.0 M2) Build id: 20160922-0846

Comment: @MisterIbbs According to Bug 502711 (linked in my answer) the fix was not implemented until M7, and you are on M2. So although you are on Oxygen you still need to [upgrade to M7](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/oxygen).